# Change making problem - Pearson algorithm to check the optimality of greedy solution

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, algorithms, computer-science, linear-programming

This is a question regarding the common version of the [Change making problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem), which is:

> "how can a given amount of money be made with the least number of coins of given denominations (we have infinite copies of each coin)"

Specifically, regarding determining whether a given coin system is canonical (canonical = greedy approach is always best). The paper by Pearson [A Polynomial-Time Algorithm for the Change-Making Problem](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwielOOV6MvwAhUQr6QKHQstBToQFjAAegQIBRAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.57.3243%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&usg=AOvVaw1w-jVA_YnRuVrb83dSctpN) provides a polynomial-time, O(n^3) algorithm for doing so, which from what I've gathered is the best to date.

However, sadly, I just for the life of me cannot understand what that algorithm actually is from reading this paper, due to the very formal language used.

My question is of the "simple but not easy" variety - Could I ask you fine folks to give me a simple "real" example of how Pearson's algorithm works? Let's take a simple non-canonical coin set - 1, 2, 4, 5 or 1, 2, 3, 6, 17, 21 (whichever is more instructive). How exactly does one run the Pearson check with these specific values? Thanks in advance for taking the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theorem $1$ in the paper gives an algorithm for constructing $O(n^2)$ possible minimal counterexamples to the assertion that the system is canonical.  Each of these can be tested in linear time.  If none of the potential counterexamples is in fact a counterexample, then there is no counterexample, and the system is canonical.

Consider the coin system $$21,17,6,3,2,1$$ with $6$ denominations.  For each choice of integers $1<i\leq j \leq n$ the algorithm constructs a potential counterexample.  Number the coins in decreasing order, so that $c_1=21,\dots, c_6=1$.  First, we construct the greedy representation of $c_{i-1}-1$.  So, if $i=2$, we construct the greedy representation of $c_1-1=20$, which the paper calls $G(20)$.  $$G(20)=(0,1,0,1,0,0)$$ meaning that we use one coin of value $17$ and one of value $3$.

Let's say that $j=3$.  Theorem $1$ says that a potential minimal counterexample agrees with $G(20)$ in positions $1$ through $j-1$, is $1$ more in position $j$ and $0$ elsewhere.  That is $$M(w)=(0,1,1,0,0,0)$$  This is a representation of $23$ $(17+6)$.  The greedy representation of $23$ is $(1,0,0,0,1,0)$ $(21+2)$.  Both representations have size $2$, so $23$ is not the minimal counterexample.

On the other hand, let's keep $i=2$ and try $j=2$.  Theorem $1$ gives us $$M(w)=(0,2,0,0,0,0)$$ which is a representation of $34$ of size $2$.  The greedy representation of $34$ is $$(1,0,2,0,0,1)$$ of size $4$, so the system is not canonical, and $34$ is the minimal counterexample.

**CLARIFICATION**

Since there have been a couple of questions about it, I should explain that $i$ and $j$ represent the first and last non-zero positions in the minimal counterexample $M(w)$, so that we must have $i\leq j$.

Comment: I see. A quick question, you said that a potential minimal counterexample agrees with G(20) in positions 1 through j−1, is 1 more in position j and 0 elsewhere. That is
M(w)=(0,1,1,0,0,0)   - that is for j = 4.

But if we were to contruct it from G(20)=(0,1,0,1,0,0), shouldn't it be
M(w)=(0,1,0,2,0,0)? (the same thing for positions 1 through 3), 1 more on position j, and 0 elsewhere?

Comment: The same goes for the M(w) for j = 3 If we start with G(20)=(0,1,0,1,0,0), and do the transform it in the following way - the same thing from 1 to j-1, then whatever is at position j increased by one then zeros, shouldn't we get M(w)=(0,1,1,0,0,0) ?

Comment: @Entman I messed up the indices.  I think I've got it right now.

Comment: Yeah, the indices are fine now! Makes perfect sense now. So just to clarify, we compare the sizes of M(w), and the greedy representation of the number M(w) represents?
Let's take j = 3 i =3

C(i-1)-1 = 16
g(16) =  0 0 2 1 0 1

m(w) = 0 0 3 0 0 0    (which is 18)

number m(w) reps, greedy - 0 0 3 0 0 0

because representations of the last 2 (m(w) and the number m(w) represents) are of the same size, it is not a counterexample, is that correct?

Comment: @Entman Yes, that's correct.

Comment: thank you very much for your explanation, everything is crystal clear now. Just as a little bonus question ;) do you happen to know how the whole check behaves if we apply it to systems which do not contain a coin with the value of "1"? Is a system like that automatically non-canonical? Because, for instance, if we were to take a system of 2 3 4 5, aside from the fact that it cannot produce "1" it is both complete (it can produce everything sans 1) and canonical (meaning for all values it can produce greedy is best)

Comment: @Entman I don't know the answer to that question, but it's interesting.  It's sort of related to the [Frobenius coin problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem).  You might want to ask another question.

Comment: and also, as a non-bonus question - in the paper, it is stated that "Let M(w)=(m1,m2, . . . , mn), and let i and j denote the first and last nonzero entries in M(w) respectively, i.e. mi = 0 and mj = 0, and mk =0 for 1≤k<i and j <k≤n." From these it would appear that j < k < i, but your explanation has i ≤ j. Are these symbols referring to the same thing?

Comment: Yes, but we don't know what $i$ and $j$ are, so we have to try all possible values.  Also, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  I have trouble reading what you are writing.

Comment: Hi @saulspatz sorry for being a bit late, but I have the same question as Entman, why is $1 \leq i  \leq j$? I understand that we don't know the values for i and j but wouldn't we need to try for all $n\geq i \geq 1$ and all $n\geq j \geq 1$? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @SantiagoPardal What is there in my answer to Entman that you don't understand?  Have you read the paper?  How are $i$ and $j$ defined?

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks for your answer, yes I have read the paper, from what I understand $i$ would be the index in the representation set, for instance $c_i$ would be the coin "number" $i$ in the set and the i-th coin with the largest denomination. On the other hand, $j$ will be the number up to which all the elements in $M(w)$ are equal to $G(c_{i-1}-1)$, this is, $M(w)=[m_1, m_2, ..., m_{j-1}, g_j+1, ..., m_n]$ and $G(c_{i-1}-1)=[m_1, m_2, ..., m_{j-1}, g_j, ..., g_n]$ am I wrong?

Comment: @SantiagoPardal If I remember right, $i$ and $j$ are as defined in the third paragraph on page $4$, so that $i$ must be $\leq j$.  See if you agree.  (My short-term memory is all but non-existent, so I may be wrong.)  Ping me again if this doesn't help, and I'll look at the paper again.

Comment: @saulspatz You are a genius and your memory is great! Don't know why I couldn't see it. Thank you so much!